# how to deploy to remote server with tomcat7-maven-plugin

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

i want to use tomcat7-maven-plugin to deploy war file from my local machine to remote server, here's the configuration i have so far:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <server>pb</server>
                  <url>http://mydomain.com:8080/manager/html</url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

do i need more configuration ? and what command do i use to deploy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have to add the following to **settings.xml**:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">


  <servers>
  <server>
        <id>pb</id>
        <username>myuser</username>
        <password>mypass</password>
  </server>
  </servers>

</settings>
```

and use the command `mvn tomcat7:deploy`